# How to import HTML content (No Styles) into Text Field?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have some information in an HTML file. There are more HTML files, which all contains strings which depends on an input parameter(bold).

as an Example:

```
file_**01**.html    --> contains: "Bob Bakers"

file_**02**.html    --> contains: "Alice Armstrong"
```

The HTML files are stored in the repository and I would like to import/load the content of one of these files into a textfield. With some images I've done something similia like:

```
 "repo:/home/res/images/" + $F{html_param} + ".html"
```

And depending on the parameter, it loads the right image. I need to do the same with the strings from the HTML files.

If it is not possible to do this with an Text Field, are there other options to import/load the content and show them in the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
        <textField>
            <reportElement .../>
            <textElement markup="html"/>
            <textFieldExpression>new String(net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInstance($P{JASPER_REPORTS_CONTEXT}).getBytesFromLocation("repo:/home/res/images/" + $F{html_param} + ".html"), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)</textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

This would work as long as the html file structure is simple, otherwise `markup="html"` might fail to interpret the document.